# ostream::write - What happens when my streamsize is smaller than my char

Tags: c++, file, binary, ostream

I am using this function to write binary files:

```
ostream& write (const char* s, streamsize n);
```

I'm wondering what happens when my streamsize **n** is smaller than my **s**. My original code looks something like this:

```
int new_number = 10;
out.write((char*) &new_number, sizeof (new_number));
```

Can you predict what happens when I change it to:

```
int new_number = 10;
out.write((char*) &new_number, 2);
```

Is it a possible way to save disk space?
Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to store a 24 bit integer.

Comment: _"Is it a possible way to save disk space?"_ No! If you want _to save disk space_, use a different number type like e.g. `short`.

Comment: It will write the two low-order bytes of the binary representation of `new_number`. Since the binary representation is implementation-defined, the results are unpredictable, technically speaking. On a typical little-endian two's-complement machine, it would be equivalent to `int16_t temp = static_cast<int16_t>(new_number); out.write((char*) &temp, sizeof(temp));`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to store a 24 bit integer. But there is no data type for this

Comment: Something along these lines: `uint32_t number = whatever(); unit8_t temp[3] = {static_cast<unit8_t>(number), static_cast<unit8_t>(number>>8), static_cast<unit8_t>(number>>16)}; out.write((char*)temp, sizeof(temp));`

Comment: @Birdperson _" I want to store a 24 bit integer"_ A `uint32_t` would serve that well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: As long as you don't mind wasting 8 bits for each stored value.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Probably better than struggling with `uint8_t[3]`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "It will write the two low-order bytes of ..." Only on a little-endian system. On a big-endian system it'll do something else entirely...

Comment: @twalberg I suppose I chose sloppy wording. I meant "bytes at the lower addresses", not "least-significant bytes".

Answer (score 0):

This will write the first two bytes of the `int` representation. This will work in some situations, but isn't portable:

- if the machine's byte-ordering isn't *little-endian*, then you'll lose the value;
- if the value is too large to be represented by two bytes, then you'll get the wrong value;
- if the value might be negative, then you'll need to be careful how you read it back;
- if `int` is smaller than two bytes, then you won't save space.

It would be safer to convert to a fixed-size type, like `int16_t`, checking the range if necessary.